# How to move files from home/user.backup back to home/user?

Tags: 16.04, permissions, files, backup

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS with Desktop Environment XFCE 4. I tried to install Second Life on my comp so after typing in the terminal `sudo install.sh` I got asked about directory I would like to install it to, so I typed `home/user`. Then the terminal window disappeared, files from `home/user` disappeared and folder `home/user.backup` appeared. When I try to use Thunar with sudo to move the files back, I get `No protocol specified` and `Thunar: Cannot open display`

How can I move this files (including hidden) back to `home/user` folder?

Answer (score 2):

You probably did more harm trying to move the files back. If you have not done anything to the two directories, you could simply renaming them back to what they was before. I.e.,

```
sudo mv /home/user /home/mygame
sudo mv /home/user.backup /home/user
```

It is unclear what you have done when you says trying to move the files back. May be you can describe all the steps you did already so we can find a way to reverse those operations. If the software you try to use hasn't done anything harmful yet, the above commands should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I don't think I did anything harmful(other then causing this problem). All files are in home/user.backup folder so I'll follow your advice (after copying the files on some external disc just in case).

Comment: It worked partially. When I changed the names user.backup folder with all it's content disappeared from home and appeared in new home/user folder. After restarting the comp, I had non of my user settings including wallpaper and stuff but at least I had an access to most of the files and knew that I didn't kill permanently anything, so I moved all files from now home/user/user.backup to home/user using sudo cp command and after restarting the comp I got all back in it's place. Just need to change ownership of the folders home/user to root and home/mygame to user and job's done. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you have this resolved, some installation scripts are quite badly made and unforgiving. It appears that in this case the install script is expecting an empty directory rather than a path to create the game directory. Quite unusual.